# AuthGroupFile - support for nested groups?

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm currently using groups managed in a simple text file to allow for read and write access to various ressources:

```
res1-r: alice bob
res1-w: zak
```

This file is used with the `AuthGroupFile` directive. With the groups file growing steadily, I'd like to establish some kind of "subgrouping". Let's assume that `alice` and `bob` are members of a team and I'd like to grant read access to the entire team. In effect, I'd like to write something like:

```
ateam: alice bob
res1-r: @ateam
```

Is this possible - either directly or through some workaround?

Comment: AFAIK: no this isn't possible.  You are going to need to switch to another authentication back-end.   Perhaps something ldap based?

Comment: @Zoredache: The user management is already LDAP-based, but due to the way our AD is managed, it would be way more complicated to have the groups managed in the AD (I have to go to some other team to have changes affected there, takes up to 4 days) than simply editing the text file itself. Well, maybe some script-based meta-groups-to-groups-compiler then. If you'll add your 'no' as an answer (and nothing else turns up), I'll mark it as accepted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used the following perl script to get the job done:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

if ($#ARGV != 0) {
    die "Usage: agc <target file>\n";
}

our %groups;

my $dstfilename = "$ARGV[0]";
my $srcfilename = "$ARGV[0].src";
open (SRCFILE, $srcfilename) or die "Could not open $srcfilename.\n";
while (<SRCFILE>) {
    chomp;
    if ($_ =~ /^(.*)\s*:\s*(.*)$/) {
        $groups{$1} = $2;
    }
}
close (SRCFILE);

open (DSTFILE, ">$dstfilename") or die "Could not open $dstfilename.\n";
print DSTFILE "# CAUTION: This file was generated from $srcfilename.\n";
print DSTFILE "# DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY - all changes will be lost upon re-generation.\n";
print DSTFILE "# Instead, edit $srcfilename and run 'agc $dstfilename'.\n";
foreach my $key (sort (keys (%groups))) {
    print DSTFILE "$key:";
    my @elems = split(/\s/, $groups{$key});
    foreach my $elem (@elems) {
        if ($elem =~ /^@(.*)/) {
            print DSTFILE " " . $groups{$1};
        } else {
            print DSTFILE " $elem";
        }
    }
    print DSTFILE "\n";
}
close (DSTFILE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this possible? Probably. Is it a good idea? Nope.

It looks like kind of like you're trying to reinvent the wheel. Apache supports a pretty wide variety of authentication backends and since it looks like your organization already has an LDAP implementation in the form of Active Directory I would recommend you take a look at [mod_authnz_ldap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html). In the long run, I'm willing to bet the time it takes to implement, maintain and *secure* your text file based system will be significantly more than the time it takes to work with your Directory Services team.